# How to calculate the aggregate variance in pivot table

Tags: pandas, pivot-table

when I use `aggfunc = np.var` in pivot table. I found the value of metrics became `NaN`. But when it comes to `aggfunc = np.sum` it doesn't.

why the original value was changed with `aggfunc = np.var` or `aggfunc = np.std`. I can not found answer in the docs. [docs of pivot table](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html?highlight=pivot_table#pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table)

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": ["foo", "foo", "foo", "foo", "foo",
                          "bar", "bar", "bar", "bar"],
                    "B": ["one", "one", "one", "two", "two",
                          "one", "one", "two", "two"],
                    "C": ["small", "large", "large", "small",
                          "small", "large", "small", "small",
                          "large"],
                    "D": [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
                    "E": [2, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 8, 9, 9]})
print(df.pivot_table(
    index = ['A', 'B'],
    values = ['D', 'E'],
    columns = ['C'],
    aggfunc= np.sum,
    margins=True,
    margins_name = 'sum',
    dropna = False
))
print('-' * 100)
df = df.pivot_table(
    index = ['A', 'B'],
    values = ['D', 'E'],
    columns = ['C'],
    aggfunc= np.var,
    margins=True,
    margins_name = 'var',
    dropna = False
)
print(df)
```

```
            D               E          
C       large small sum large small sum
A   B                                  
bar one   4.0   5.0   9   6.0   8.0  14
    two   7.0   6.0  13   9.0   9.0  18
foo one   4.0   1.0   5   9.0   2.0  11
    two   NaN   6.0   6   NaN  11.0  11
sum      15.0  18.0  33  24.0  30.0  54
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
                D                         E                
C           large small       var     large small       var
A   B                                                      
bar one       NaN   NaN  0.500000       NaN   NaN  2.000000
    two       NaN   NaN  0.500000       NaN   NaN  0.000000
foo one  0.000000   NaN  0.333333  0.500000   NaN  2.333333
    two       NaN   0.0  0.000000       NaN   0.5  0.500000
var      5.583333   3.8  3.555556  4.666667   7.5  4.888889
```

what's more, I found the var of `D = large` is `np.var([4.0, 7.0, 4.0]) = 2.0` instead of `5.583333`.

what I expected is:

```py
            D               E          
C       large small var large small var
A   B                                  
bar one   4.0   5.0  0.25  6.0   8.0   1.0
    two   7.0   6.0  0.25  9.0   9.0   0
foo one   4.0   1.0  2.25  9.0   2.0   12.25
    two   NaN   6.0  0     NaN   11.0  0.0
var       2.0   4.25 3.6   2.0   11.25 7.34
```

**What is the meaning of `aggfunc = np.var` in pivot table?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pandas uses by [default](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.var.html) `ddof = 1`, see [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.var.html) for details on `np.var`.

When you have just one value, then the variance using `ddof = 1` will be `NaN` as you try to divide by zero.

Var of `D = large` is `np.var([2,2,4,7], ddof=1) = 5.583333333333333`, so everything is correct (you'll have to use the individual values, not the sums).

---

If you need `var` with `ddof = 0` then you can provide your own function:

```
def var0(x):
    return np.var(x, ddof=0)

print(df.pivot_table(
    index = ['A', 'B'],
    values = ['D', 'E'],
    columns = ['C'],
    aggfunc= var0,
    margins=True,
    margins_name = 'var',
    dropna = False
))
```

Result:

```
              D                     E                
C         large small       var large small       var
A   B                                                
bar one  0.0000  0.00  0.250000  0.00  0.00  1.000000
    two  0.0000  0.00  0.250000  0.00  0.00  0.000000
foo one  0.0000  0.00  0.222222  0.25  0.00  1.555556
    two     NaN  0.00  0.000000   NaN  0.25  0.250000
var      4.1875  3.04  3.555556  3.50  6.00  4.888889
```

---

**UPDATE based on the edited question**.
Pivot table with the sums of `C` and additionally the var of the sums as margin columns/row.

We first create the `sum` pivot table with margin columns/row named `var`. Then we updated these margin columns/row with the `var` of the `sum` table:

```
dfs = df.pivot_table(
    index = ['A', 'B'],
    values = ['D', 'E'],
    columns = ['C'],
    aggfunc= np.sum,
    margins=True,
    margins_name = 'var',
    dropna = False)

dfs[[('D','var'),('E','var')]] = df.pivot_table(
    index = ['A', 'B'],
    values = ['D', 'E'],
    columns = ['C'],
    aggfunc= np.sum,
    dropna = False).stack().groupby(level=(0,1)).apply(var0)
dfs.iloc[-1] = dfs.iloc[:-1].apply(var0)
```

Result:

```
            D                     E                  
C       large small       var large  small        var
A   B                                                
bar one   4.0  5.00  0.250000   6.0   8.00   1.000000
    two   7.0  6.00  0.250000   9.0   9.00   0.000000
foo one   4.0  1.00  2.250000   9.0   2.00  12.250000
    two   NaN  6.00  0.000000   NaN  11.00   0.000000
var       2.0  4.25  0.824219   2.0  11.25  26.792969
```

In the margin row (last row) the var columns are calculated as the var of the row vars. I don't understand how the OP calculated his values for these two cells. Anyway they don't seem to make much sense.

Comment: @Lydoo Please see my update for var after sum, although I couldn't figure out how you arrived at 3.55 and 4.88 for the var/var cells.

Comment: Sry, I have made a mistake. Actually, I want to calculate the var of all values of `D` after pivot_table with `aggfunc = sum`.  Your answer helps a lot, thank you!